# How to use windows phone class Library

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have solution wp8 include phone app Demo and windows phone class library (dll). Demo has Test.xaml, Dll project has TestDLL.xaml. So how can i display TestDLL.xaml from Test.xaml, get return object from TestDll.xaml and turn back Test.xaml after finish Test1.xaml.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Make sure that your question is clear and understand by others.

Answer (score 0):

Do the follwing steps

Right click on `Reference`
Select `Add reference`
Select `Solutions`
There will be the list of projects or dlls available in your solution.
Just tick the item and Click `Add`.

Answer (score 0):

Go through this steps:

1. Right click on `References`
2. Select `Add Reference..`
3. When you click on add reference you will see some option i.e. `Assemblies`,`Solution`,`Browse`. If you have added Windows Phone class Library project in same solution then click on solution otherwise browse it.
4. Select appropriate `dll` and just click on **Add** button.

after adding `reference` you can see it in `references` folder.